# Get textbox and checkbox value for each row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I've this code

```
<tr class="CheckboxRow">
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="7" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="2" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="3" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="4" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="5" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="6" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="FromTimeTextboxCol">
    <input name="" type="text" class="FromTime" />
  </td>
  <td class="ToTimeTextboxCol">
    <input name="" type="text" class="ToTime" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="CheckboxRow">
<td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="7" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="2" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="3" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="4" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="5" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="CheckboxCol">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" value="6" class="Checkbox" />
  </td>
  <td class="FromTimeTextboxCol">
    <input name="" type="text" class="FromTime" />
  </td>
  <td class="ToTimeTextboxCol">
    <input name="" type="text" class="ToTime" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Now i want to check that for each corresponding row atleast one checkbox must be checked and `FromTime` and `ToTime` textbox should have value, Else a required message should be displayed for that row.

How can i achive this using JavaScript or Jquery on input button click?

**Note:** I'm not assigning id to any field as the number of rows can be added dynamically to the page.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far???

Comment: @Kartikeya: i don't have a clue about how it is to be done..that's why i posted it..any help or idea would be very helpful.

Comment: A good place to start would be: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#TableTbody tr").each(function(i,row){

$(row).find("YourElementClassName").val();
//perform Check Here...

})
```